# passing *args/**kwargs in a derived class

Tags: python, inheritance

I need to understand the following behavior

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FactoryTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    swift = FactoryLogs.get_service('freezer')
  File "/home/iob/Devel/elastic_tests/elasticFactory.py", line 12, in get_service
    return Factory.create_factory(service)
  File "/home/iob/Devel/elastic_tests/factory.py", line 11, in create_factory
    return FreezerLogs()
  File "/home/iob/Devel/elastic_tests/elasticFactory.py", line 68, in __init__
    super(FreezerLogs, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

This is raised when I try to create an instance of a derived and call a method defined in its base class.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.att1='a'

  def _foo(self):
    self.bar(*args, **kwargs)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
    super(B,self).__init__()

    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
      #code
```

Then I create an instance of type B and I call the bar. I feel that many things go wrong here and i need some to enlighten me because reading the doc and other resources online, i felt more confused.

Comment: You're calling a function (bar) that doesn't exist for the class A. It only exists for the Class B, so you can only call it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get indicates that you are probably attempting to use `super` with old-style classes. Unfortunately, this doesn't work and has to be fixed either by switching to new-style classes or by invoking the superclass without the use of `super`.

If you are in control of the base classes, make sure that they inherit from `object`. Otherwise, do not use `super`, but call the base class constructor directly:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        # ...
```

Comment: Why not use super().__init__()? As far as I'm aware there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @Nallath The error reported by OP indicates the use of old-style classes, which are not supported by `super`.

Comment: @Nallath super().__init__ i think works for python3 but not in python2.7

Comment: @user4815162342 thank you very much. this seems to have solved one problem but now I get another issue. it returns NameError: global name 'args' is not defined. Can you explain that?

Comment: @b10n1k It's hard to tell without seeing the exact code. Based on what you've shown, `A._foo` uses `args` and `kwargs` without setting (or receiving them anywhere). I'm not sure what the intention was, but this other problem probably warrants a separate question.

Comment: @Nallath Also, Python 3 doesn't have old-style classes, so the original exception wouldn't have occurred there in the first place.